# Javascript clone text from anchor and add to attribute of same anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to clone the text from anchor and set it as title attribute to same anchor but do not get the logic how to use the syntax correct.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.desc a').clone(true,true).appendTo($('.desc a').attr('title', ''));
});
```

```html
<div class="desc">
  <a href="somedomain">Somedomain</a>
  <a href="somedomain2">Somedomain2</a>
</div>
```

Would be happy for a small help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if I understand correctly, but if you want to get the text and set it back to the same anchor you do not need to clone the a tag:

```
function setTitle(node){
    node.setAttribute("title",node.textContent)
    return node;
}

[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.desc a')).forEach((d)=>setTitle(d));
```